# Getting an explicit representation of the function returned from Interpolation

Tags: functions, interpolation

I am using `Interpolation` to get an `InterpolatingFunction` that fits a set of points. For example,

```
points = {{6, 14}, {2, 0.15}, {...}, {...}, ...};
func = Interpolation[points];
```

which returns an `InterpolatingFunction`. I understand that [Interpolate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) does a piecewise polynomial interpolation to fit the data. My question is, how do I get the explicit definition of this piecewise function from the `InterpolatingFunction` object? I want to do this with an arbitrary interpolation order, not specifically the maximum data points. For example, I want to see the form:

```
func = {{x^2 + 2, x < 2}, {1 - x^3 + 3, x >= 2}, ...}
```

I see something like this at the bottom of the `InterpolatingFunction` documentation page as linked above, but the writer seemed to already know the locations at which the `InterpolatingFunction` was split between the piecewise fits.

Comment: Perhaps as a start you could differentiate the `InterpolatingFunction` to identify the intervals.

Comment: In this video we can learn to make a kinetic analysis of a mechanical arm applying polynomial interpolation
https://youtu.be/v9p_2utyjgw

Answer (score 5):

I do not know how to extract that information from an `InterpolatingFunction` object, but perhaps you could make your own `Piecewise` function using `InterpolatingPolynomial`:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {10, 2}];
piecewise = Piecewise[
  {InterpolatingPolynomial[#, x], #[[1, 1]] <= x < #[[2, 1]]} & /@ 
   Partition[SortBy[First][pts], 2, 1]
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is a plot of the `Interpolation` result and of the `Piecewise` function together (the built-in interpolation is offset by three vertical units for clarity):

```
Plot[{
  piecewise,
  Interpolation[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x] + 3
  },
 Evaluate@Flatten@{x, MinMax[pts[[All, 1]]]},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[1];

pts = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {10, 2}];

Clear[if, ip]
```

If the [`InterpolationOrder`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolationOrder.html) is set to `Length[pts] - 1` then the [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) is the [`InterpolatingPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html)

```
if[x_] = Interpolation[pts, InterpolationOrder -> Length[pts] - 1][x];

ip[x_] = InterpolatingPolynomial[pts, x] // HornerForm

(*  -18.7844 + 
 x (6.55948 + 
    x (11.9763 + 
       x (-0.292684 + 
          x (-1.04441 + 
             x (0.030186 + 
                x (0.0317666 + 
                   x (-0.00161601 + (-0.000321526 + 0.0000231103 x) x)))))))  *)

Plot[{if[x], ip[x]},
 {x, Min[pts[[All, 1]]], Max[pts[[All, 1]]]},
 PlotStyle -> {Dashed, DotDashed},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is potentially useful so thanks, but I'd like to be able to get the function for an arbitrary interpolation order, not just specifically

        Length[pts] - 1

For example, if the order was 3, I'd like to see all of the cubic function definitions and what intervals they'd apply on.